# Setting Cookie on Ajax request to outside domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cookies, cors

I am having some trouble getting around cross domain issues. In particular we are trying to load content from an outside domain (which we control) inside an iframe. In order to prevent having the user log in each time in the iframe, we want to set a user cookie on the iframe. In order to do this, we created an iframe, and had an ajax call request the content, and used a beforeSend callback that would set the header on the request.

However we're encountering some issues that we can't resolve. In particular CORS seems to impose an OPTIONS request, is there anyway of getting around this? Oddly enough if we put the url of the resource straight into the iframe definition, it does not complain about a failed OPTIONS request, but continues normally. It is only if we try a ajax request or a simple $.get("...") request.

Why would it allow an iframe request to complete and not an ajax call in this scenario?

Below are the response headers

`Response Headers
access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-headers:*
access-control-allow-methods:PUT, DELETE, POST, GET OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin:*
access-control-expose-headers:*
connection:keep-alive
content-length:2474
content-security-policy:
content-type:text/html
date:Tue, 19 Apr 2016 10:38:07 GMT
server:TornadoServer/4.3`

Answer (score 1):

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is there for security reasons:

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts.  For example, XMLHttpRequest follows
>   the same-origin policy. So, a web application using XMLHttpRequest
>   could only make HTTP requests to its own domain.

The XMLHttpRequest is used for the ajax calls and the browser is probbably blocking it.

As a workaround, if you control the server-side, you can add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to then response, so the browser won't block this ajax call.

For example, in **PHP** (I don't know what server technology are you using, use this as example) you could do (at the top of your script):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Or, if you want to allow only the calls from your domain:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com');
```

**EDIT**

You should/could also define what METHODS do your CORS call accept with the header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: Our server side uses django, we have control over tornado header settings, and we've added the needed headers. In stead we see that it returns 405 which might mean we'd need to implement an options endpoint in the code. However we don't have control over the code just the configuration options.